# how to store matrix data or tabular data and easy to retrieve data in android

Tags: android

I have a one application .In this application  data are available in tabular format .

How to store this data in android .use database or any other option .

[image]

Easy calculation using above data .

Please help me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u may create an array
    data[group][time]  17-18=1.22-26=2
data[A][0]=100; data[A][1]=99;  22-26=B
data[2][0]=100; and so on